# Checking for Empty Text Fields And Running Script Based on Results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<input name="FirstName" id="FirstName" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" type="text" placeholder="First Name*"> 

<input name="LastName" id="LastName" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" type="text" placeholder="Last Name*">

<input name="EmailAddress" id="EmailAddress" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail Address*">
```

**JS**

```
$( ".prep-form" ).on( "click", function() {

var name = $.trim($('#FirstName').val()),
    nachName = $.trim($('#LastName').val()),
    eMail = $.trim($('#EmailAddress').val());

if (name == '' || nachName == '' || eMail == '') {

    // SHOW ERROR MESSAGE

} else if //Continue with script -- Note: The script works fine until I add the above code...

  return false;
});
```

As you can see I am checking three input fields to see if they are empty. If any of the three are empty I show an error message, otherwise the script should continue to run.

When I try the above code, regardless of what is in the input fields, the script will only show the error message.

What is wrong?

Comment: `If any of the three are empty I show an error message`. Shouldn't there be an `OR` condition?

Comment: @PramodKarandikar - You are correct. I edited my code, however, the issue still arises.

Comment: @Tushar - The other code is irrelevant and the script works if I remove the if statement I posted.

Comment: You can try the other way `if (name || nachName  || eMail ) {// valid } else { throw error }`

Comment: I would check against the length of the String-values. like: `name.length === 0 || ...` also: don't use 'trim' against a jQuery-Object (see Mukesh Kalgude's answer).

Comment: @PramodKarandikar - That didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @Lynda are you sure your selectors are correct? That's the only reason I can see this failing.

Comment: @billyonecan - Yes, I added the HTML code with the selectors.

Comment: @Lynda Okay - is your js inside of an event handler? Are you sure the dom has fully loaded before the js is executed?

Comment: @billyonecan - It is in an click event. See the updated answer.

Comment: *Updated question, not answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure what was wrong with my code but I found a solution using the following code:

```
var x = document.forms["formName"]["FirstName"].value;
var y = document.forms["formName"]["LastName"].value;
var z = document.forms["formName"]["EmailAddress"].value;

if (x == null || x == "") {

    //Show Alert

return false;

} else if (y == null || y == "") {

    //Show Alert

return false;

} else if (y == null || y == "") {

    //Show Alert

return false;

} else { 

//Once those above validate the script continues running
```